Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Not Attaching Headset/Mic via 3.5mm jack
Some details that may help

Ubuntu: 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic
AORUS Laptop
Fully updated as of writing this.

My current issue is that I plug in a razer headset and only the headphones are picked up. So my internal mic is all I can use. No amount of unplugs/restarts changes this behavior. Attached is a screenshot of what I see and no there is nothing else under the Input Device.
Yes the device works I have a usb sound card that I can plug in and get both the headphones and mic.

For troubleshooting I found (not sure pulseaudio makes any sense here) (these are different links btw)

Headset microphone is not working in ubuntu 20.04
Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04

I get my codec

Codec: Realtek ALC255

Based on that and kernel.org I added the following to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf at the end of the file:
# Trying to fix a headset to get my mic
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=alc255-asus,laptop-amic,headset-mic

After a restart there is no change. I tried a few other variations of this but I am not fully understanding what I am attempting with this.

You have failed to say how it is connected. Is it Bluetooth, or 3.5 jack or some other type of device? Please edit the question and ad this info.

@DavidDE Sorry I had "plug in" thought that might be enough. I added the context to the title.

I am having the same problem.

(Using a Lenovo ThinkPad P72.)

It is either a driver or an audio system problem. I recommend installing "pipewire", the successor of "pulseaudio" (if not already installed) - check my answer

@kanehekili pipewire is already installed.

Had a ton of issues with my headset (a generic redragon) and this solved my problem: https://yktoo.com/en/software/sound-switcher-indicator/installation/
It does exactly the same job os AudioPulse, but solved my problems with mic and headset.
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher


Thank you for this answer. To my mind, an ideal answer will not rely on third party solutions, but settings, bug-fixes, etc. within the 24.04/46 system.

First, dumb question time. Have you tried the drop down arrow on the mic input setting and seeing if there is another mic?
Second, on the command line try dmesg | grep -i audio  and see if the error log is showing any errors being thrown.
Third, on the command line enter arecord -l to check and see if the mic is listed as being recognized correctly.
Fourth, try adding options snd-hda-intel model=generic  to the end of sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf instead of what you have entered.
Finally, on the command line enter alsamixer. See if anything happens to be muted.
Any one or all of these could be the answer. Let me know if none of this produces a result.
`

"Have you tried the drop down arrow on the mic input setting and seeing if there is another mic?" Yes, of course.

dmesg | grep -i audio  gives nothing.

arecord -l mic is not listed/not recognized.

alsamixer (cute interface!) does not list anything as muted.

Ok, we are making progress. Reading your original post, this is a USB connected device, correct? Let us see if it is registering at the usb level. On the command line, lsusb. Does it show your Razer in the output?

Let's also rule out Pulseaudio being sketchy. Command Line, pulseaudio --kill then pulseaudio --start. These kill the process then restart it. pavucontrol to open the PulseAudio display and see if the mic shows there.

Nope. It's not a USB-conncted device. Notice the repeated mention of 3.5mm jack. Also, this is 24.04, pipewire is the default in the installation.

I did not see repeated mentions of 3.5mm, I did see "...I have a usb sound card that I can plug in". By your tone it sounds like you have it under control. I'm sure you will find the answer you are looking for. Ta.

The title of the question is literally "Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Not Attaching Headset/Mic via 3.5mm jack" But no: I have not seen anyone provide a solution.
